# How to set different etherscan api for different networks in foundry

Tags: foundry, forge

I'm in the process of deploying the same contract across two different blockchains, with the intention of verifying them once deployed. I have obtained the API keys from Etherscan for both networks. However, I'm uncertain about how to configure the `foundry.toml` file to facilitate this.

Ideally I would like to run something like `forge script contract_path --rpc-url $BASE --etherscan-api-key BASE_KEY --broadcast --verify`